# Python Grading Program

Tags: python, function, loops

So I need to make a program that grades 10 students individually, then displays the average grade for all 10 students.

I think this is how the grading should look, but im not sure how to set up a count on the number of times its graded, or how to set up the average function. Help would be most welcome. I am a horrible coder.

```
score = int(input("Enter a score between 0 and 100: "))
if score >=89:
    print("The grade is an A")
elif score>=79:
    print("The grade is a B")
elif score>=69:
    print("The grade is a C")
elif score>=59:
    print("The grade is a D")
else:
    print("The grade is a F")
```

Comment: Where do the different scores come from?

Comment: Missed a line copying it sorry! 
Ill edit it.

but the first line was:

score = int(input("Enter a score between 0 and 100: "))

Comment: Your question is very basic, but that's ok - SO is for new coders as well and you shared what you have so far. You want to do something a number of times, which means you should look at loops like `while` and `for`. And you want to keep track of something over the course of those loops, so you need to keep track in separate variable, like a running total of scores and the number of scores; another approach would be to remember all the scores given so far in a `list`, so you can compute an average and do other things with that data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using a counter variable that goes from 0-9 and use a while loop to check and increment that counter value and after each loop calculates the average and keeps doing this till the last value has been entered

```
Counter = 0
average = 0
while (Counter <= 10):
    score = int(input("Enter a score between 0 and 100: "))
    if score >= 89:
        print("The grade is an A")
    elif score >= 79:
        print("The grade is a B")
    elif score >= 69:
        print("The grade is a C")
    elif score >= 59:
        print("The grade is a D")
    else:
        print("The grade is a F")
    Counter = Counter + 1
    average = (score + average)
average  = average/Counter

print("Average of all 10 students:",average)
```

So right now the code is configured specifically for just 10 loops but you can give the user the power to determine this by suggesting a value to end the loop and the while loop will check for this value and when the loop sees the value it exits the loop and gives a value

Also with each loop there is a counter value that keeps increasing and an average value that holds the sum of the values entered and when the loop exits and average is calculated by dividing the sum by the counters and this gives the results

Comment: Language wise I think this one makes the most sense.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```py
total = 0
for i in range(10):
    score = int(input("Enter a score between 0 and 100: "))
    if score >= 89:
        print("The grade is an A")
    elif score >= 79:
        print("The grade is a B")
    elif score >= 69:
       print("The grade is a C")
    elif score >= 59:
        print("The grade is a D")
    else:
        print("The grade is a F")
    total += score

print("Average of all 10 students:", total/10)
```

In the `for` loop you get the score of each student and then add it to the total of all students. When the loop ends you divide it with the total number of students so **10**.

`total score / total number of students` **`total / 10`**

Comment: This is what I was going for. Sorry to bother you for something so basic haha!

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function that finds the average score. Store all the scores in a list and then pass the list as an argument in the function

```
def avg(scores): #assuming scores is the name of the list
    avg = sum(scores)/len(scores) 
    return "Average score is {}".format(avg)
```

Or 
        return f'Average score is {avg}' #for python3

Not sure I understand what you mean by number of times it is graded but I think you can include a while loop and a variable that increases by 1 every time it grades.

Comment: Yeah I'm not the best at wording things. Might be why I'm such a horrible coder. But this is a pretty cool way of doing it! I had to google some stuff but I think I get it now.